# Spring boot + Spring security with AspectJ not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, aspectj

I am trying to configure spring global method security with AspectJ advice mode so I can use `@PreAuthorize` annotations in all `@Configurable` annotated classes. This my java configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
```

and:

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class WebApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

This is my `@Configurable` class:

```
@Configurable
public class Entity {
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(this, 'publish')")
    public void method() { }
}
```

I also added spring-security-aspects as dependency. From AspectJ logs I can clearly see that Spring security related aspects are applied on my `@Configurable` classes however as soon as I create instance of these classes I get this exception:

```
Post-processor tried to replace bean instance of type [com.example.Entity] with (proxy) object of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130] - not supported for aspect-configured classes!
```

I am using spring boot version 1.2.1 therefore spring security version is 3.2.5 . This seems to be bug that was discussed here : [Spring Security AspectJMode with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207933/spring-security-aspectjmode-with-enableglobalmethodsecurity-not-working)

However this bug should not affect my version of spring security... Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved this. It was problem with spring boot's SecurityAutoConfiguration class. I had to exclude it from auto configuration and configre spring security manually - not very big deal, but anyway...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how you disabled the auto configuration and the beans you had to setup manually? I'm trying to get this working myself and encountering the same error message with Spring Boot and AspectJ.